# How to get all the directories where Django 2.0 will look for templates?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I want to retrieve the list of all the possible directories where Django will search for template files. I would like to make an iterable list of those directories

I tried the following :

```
def get_template_directories():
    template_directories = []
    for template in settings.TEMPLATES:
        for directory in template['DIRS']:
            template_directories.append(directory)
return template_directories
```

But, I want all the directories where Django looks for template, including templates in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Is there any internal APIs used by the Django framework to identify the directories ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched in Django and couldn't find any helpful APIs to get all the directories containing templates in Django. I finally decided to write my code like the following:

```
def get_template_directories():
    template_directories = []

    # Getting templates in the templates directory
    for template in settings.TEMPLATES:
        for directory in template['DIRS']:
            template_directories.append(directory)

    # Getting templates from INSTALLED_APPS
    for app in  settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        path = join(apps.get_app_config(app.split('.')[-1]).path, 'templates')
        if exists(path):
            template_directories.append(path)

    return template_directories
```

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS will contain apps like django.contrib.auth. We nee app.split('.')[-1] to clean that.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer did not work for me, so I updated it to work with newer Django versions, as a management command:

```
""" Refer to help variable below
"""
from pathlib import Path

from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


def get_template_directories(site_packages=False, verbose=False):
    man_dirs = []
    for template in settings.TEMPLATES:
        man_dirs.extend(template['DIRS'])
    app_dirs = []
    for app in apps.get_app_configs():
        path = f'{app.path}/templates'
        Path(path).is_dir() and app_dirs.append(path)
    app_dirs.sort()
    if not site_packages:
        man_dirs = [x for x in man_dirs if 'site-packages' not in str(x)]
        app_dirs = [x for x in app_dirs if 'site-packages' not in str(x)]
    if verbose:
        print("\nManually specified dirs:\n" + "\n".join(str(x) for x in man_dirs))
        print("\nApp template dirs:\n" + "\n".join(str(x) for x in app_dirs))
    return man_dirs + app_dirs


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "This prints a list of dirs inwhich templates are searched for"
    requires_system_checks = False

    def handle(self, **options):
        get_template_directories(verbose=True)
```